# How to define <key> element to create a shortcut key for firefox extension command

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, keyset

I need to define shortcut keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to my extension's functions.

Here is what I have in my `browser.xul` overlay:

```
<keyset id="mainKeyset">
    <key oncommand="window.alert('SLASH')" 
             id="cue-cmd-1"
             keycode="VK_SLASH"
             modifiers="accel"
                />
    <key oncommand="window.alert('PERIOD')" 
             id="cue-cmd-2"
             keycode="VK_PERIOD"
             modifiers="accel"
                />
</keyset>
```

The overlay merges successfully. However the shortcut keys do not work.

If I change `keycode="VK_PERIOD"` to `key="."` and similarly `keycode="VK_SLASH"` to `key="/"`, shortcuts keys work as expected.

Since I am allowing users to assign their preferred shortcuts to commands, I need to use `keycode` attribute in order to be able to use `shift` modifier key.

What am I missing?

Comment: Thats interesting, thanks for the note on the the test using `key`. I thought it would work, ill ttest this out.

Answer (score 0):

`modifiers="accel"` is only `ctrl` on windows and linux, it is `cmd` on osx.

Try using `modifiers="control"` instead.

Comment: Same results with ````modifiers="control"````. On a side note, AFAIK using ````control```` won't work on MAC.